# swipe view screen and page doesn't reset

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, sliding-window

I am working with fragments and page Viewer and when say, I am on a scrollable page1 and have scrolled the page to the middle and when I swipe to the next scrollable page2 I want page1 to reset to the top when I swipe to it again.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code your fragment:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && getView() != null)
            <YOUR SCROLLABLE VIEW>.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
```